# adding the integers and calculating percentage and displaying the percentage using progress bar

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am developing the financial app it should take the total salary and the amount spend for corresponding things say groceries, electricity bill, transport, internet.I have taken the values and calculated the percentage now the question is since the calculated is in `double`. But the below statement takes the `int` value only but I want display in `progress bar` not in `progress dialog`.

```
progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(x);
int amount2 = b.getInt("restaurant",2);
double res = ((double)amount2/amount) * 100;
TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
txt2.setText("percentage2\t" + res);
```

the amount is the total salary and the `amount2` is restaurant bill. So now the percentage value
is in `double` and now have to display in `progress bar`.

Comment: You should try to use name which are indicative about the context.

Comment: what statement takes and int, here ? i don't see where the problem would be.

Comment: double res = ((double)amount2/amount) * 100; Here i have calculated the percentage now the calculated percentage is stored in double res in order to display the calculated percentage in progressbar i have used "progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(x);to display in progressdialog" so here "X" is integer it will not allow double and i want to display in progress bar

Answer (score 1):

Either I do not fully understand your question, or it's as simple as this:

```
int totalIncome = getTotalIncome(); //or however you retrieve the totalIncome
int restaurantExpense = bundle.getInt("restaurant", 2);
double percentage = ((double)restaurantExpense/totalIncome) * 100;
((ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.myprogressbar)).setProgress((int)percentage);
```

But I still do not know why you use a `ProgressDialog`, and then say you do not want to use it.

Edit: You can also use the `totalIncome` as maximum:

```
myProgressbar.setMax(totalIncome);
myProgressbar.setProgress(restaurantExpense);
```

Now you can omit the calculation, and you don't have to cast anything to `int`.